# Выбрать подход (библиотеку) для анализа списка из 173 000 слов

Tags: java, база-данных, строки, spring, парсер

Есть задача проанализировать список из 173 000 слов, ниже представлено задание. Помогите выбрать наиболее удобный подход. Есть ли смысл в переборе через цикл всего массива данных, или лучше создать базу данных (Postgres) и анализировать уже ее. В общем суть задачи следующая:

Вызов

Мы представили файл который называется “wordsforproblem.txt”, который содержит отсортированный list приблизительно из 173 000 слов. Слова перечислены одно слово на одной линии, не связанны пробелами и все в нижнем регистре.
Задание - написать программу, которая читает этот файл и обеспечивает следующие:

- Самое длинное сцепленное слово (то есть, слово которое состоит из маленьких в этом файле);
- 2-ое по длине сцепленное слово.
- Общее кол-во всех сцепленных слов.

Например, если файл содержит:

```
cat
cats
catsdogcats
dog
dogcatsdog
hippopotamuses
rat
ratcatdogcat
```

Наиболее длинное сцепленное слово будет 'ratcatdogcat' из 12 символов, hippopotamuses - более длинное слово, но оно не состоит из более коротких. 2-е по длине сцепленное слово, это ‘catsdogcats’ из 11 символов. Общее количество сцепленных слов - 3. Заметка, что ‘cats’ - не сцепленное слово, потому что нет слова ‘s’ в списке.

Comment: что тут скажешь, trie вам в помощь

Comment: ну или HashSet. HashSet тоже может подойти.

Comment: @tym32167 почему именное trie? Я понимаю, HashSet, не содержит повторений. Но по описанию trie из вики я не очень понимаю почему оно подходит.

Comment: @AntonSorokin trie тоже не содержит повторений и в нем проще искать подстроки, но оно кушает больше памяти, чем HashSet.

Comment: @AntonSorokin я просто [подобное](https://leetcode.com/problems/concatenated-words/) уже решал пару лет назад :)

Answer (score 1):

Решение с хешсетом довольно простое. Заполняем хешсет, пилим слова рекурсивно, ищем подстроки слова в сете. Код будет примерно такой

```
public static void Solve(String[] input) {
    HashSet<String> set = new HashSet<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < input.length; i++) set.add(input[i]);

    ArrayList<String> result = new ArrayList<>();
    String top1 = "";
    String top2 = "";

    for (int i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
        if (isCombination(set, input[i], 0)) {
            result.add(input[i]);

            if (top2.length() < input[i].length())
                top2 = input[i];

            if (top1.length() < top2.length()) {
                String temp = top1;
                top1 = top2;
                top2 = temp;
            }
        }
    }

    System.out.println(top1);
    System.out.println(top2);
    System.out.println(result.size());
}
```

Проверка строки / подстроки в сете

```
public static boolean isCombination(HashSet<String> set, String input, int startIndex) {
    if (startIndex == input.length()) return true;
    for (int i = startIndex; i <= input.length(); i++) {
        if (set.contains(input.substring(startIndex, i))) {
            if (startIndex == 0 && i == input.length()) return false;
            if (isCombination(set, input, i)) return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Тестил вот так

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String[] input = new String[]{
            "cat",
            "cats",
            "catsdogcats",
            "dog",
            "dogcatsdog",
            "hippopotamuses",
            "rat",
            "ratcatdogcat",
    };

    Solve(input);
}
```

Вывод такой

```
ratcatdogcat
catsdogcats
3
```

Крайние случаи обрабатывайте сами.

Плюсы: реализация очевидная

Минусы: проверка каждой подстроки порождает много много поисков по сету, и, соотвественно, много много посимвольных сревнений. То есть не самое быстрое решение на свете.

Answer (score 1):

Решение с Trie чуть более сложное. Надо построить Trie, потом рекурсивно по ней искать. Код такой

```
public static void Solve(String[] input) {

    var root = new Node();

    for (var w : input)
        root.AppendWord(w, 0);

    var res = new ArrayList<String>(input.length);

    String top1 = "";
    String top2 = "";

    for (var w : input)
        if (root.CheckWord(w, 0, root)) {
            res.add(w);

            if (top2.length() < w.length())
                top2 = w;

            if (top1.length() < top2.length()) {
                String temp = top1;
                top1 = top2;
                top2 = temp;
            }
        }

    System.out.println(top1);
    System.out.println(top2);
    System.out.println(res.size());
}
```

Сам узел Trie

```
static class Node {
    Node[] _nodes = new Node[26];
    private String _val = null;
```

проверка слова

```
    public boolean CheckWord(String word, int ind, Node root) {
        if (ind > word.length()) return false;

        if (ind == word.length()) {
            if (_val != null && _val != word) return true;
            return false;
        }

        if (_val != null) {
            if (root.CheckWord(word, ind, root)) return true;
        }

        var c = word.charAt(ind) - 'a';
        if (_nodes[c] == null) return false;
        return _nodes[c].CheckWord(word, ind + 1, root);
    }
```

Добавление слова

```
    public void AppendWord(String word, int level) {
        if (level == word.length()) {
            _val = word;
            return;
        }

        var c = word.charAt(level) - 'a';
        Node node;

        if (_nodes[c] != null) {
            node = _nodes[c];
        } else {
            node = new Node();
            _nodes[c] = node;
        }

        node.AppendWord(word, level + 1);
    }
}
```

Вызов

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    String[] input = new String[]{
            "cat",
            "cats",
            "catsdogcats",
            "dog",
            "dogcatsdog",
            "hippopotamuses",
            "rat",
            "ratcatdogcat",
    };

    Solve(input);    
}
```

Вывод

```
ratcatdogcat
catsdogcats
3
```

Крайние случаи на вашей совести. И ещё я тут учитывал только английские буквы в нижнем регистре.

Полюсы: поиск подстроки линеен, не надо для каждой буковки сравнтвать всю подстроку, как в сете. То есть скорость в теории быстрее, чем с сетом. На практике не проверял.

Минусы: кушает больше памяти.

Comment: Спасибо, за ответ! Сделал сам, но идея очень похоже. Сначала, сделал только на циклах, то в момент нахождения одного слова в другом, начинался новый проход по всей коллекции на возможность еще одного вхождения. Но в "рабочей" версии на всем массиве данных, компьютер "ушел" и через 4 часа был принудительно возвращен в реальность. И в дальнейшем я переписал, именно по аналогии с приведенным вариантом. Вынесут вердикт, прокомментирую. Наверно,я не правильно написал свой вопрос, ответ мне хотелось найти самому, больше интересовал более приемлемый подход, но в любом случае большое спасибо за ответ!